# how to get value from mysql with name of id column

Tags: mysql, node.js, arrays

in the users table, there is 2 column
one for id and the other one for the username;

I want to get a username from the MySQL column with the name of their id

like `{1:'ahmed', 2:'jon', 3:'rashed'}`

to use it in javascript or Node.js

any suggest

Comment: Please post code what you tried to do

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the JSON_OBJECT function, as defined here in the documentation. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-creation-functions.html

```
mysql> SELECT JSON_OBJECT('id', 87, 'name', 'carrot');
+-----------------------------------------+
| JSON_OBJECT('id', 87, 'name', 'carrot') |
+-----------------------------------------+
| {"id": 87, "name": "carrot"}            |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

In your case:

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(id, username) FROM table WHERE conditions;
```

Or for all:

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(id, username) FROM table;
```

In a table like:

```
id    |    username
-------------------
1     |    ahmed
2     |    jon
3     |    rashed
```

This should return:

```
{1:'ahmed', 2:'jon', 3:'rashed'}
```

There is more advanced discussion of the topic [here on dba.stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/192208/mysql-return-json-from-a-standard-sql-query)
but I think this answer meets your requirements.